# Autolayout constraint behave different for iOS 6.0 and iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I got stuck with the strange behaviour of Auto layout for UIScrollView & for its subview on IOS 6.0.below code snippet is being used to set content size (through auto layout approach) based on last subview (currentArticle) which is got added to scrollview (current scrollview).

```
        self.lifeStyleContentSizeLayoutArray==nil?0:[currentScrollView removeConstraints:self.lifeStyleContentSizeLayoutArray];
        self.lifeStyleContentSizeLayoutArray=nil;
        self.lifeStyleContentSizeLayoutArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[currentArticleView]-|"] options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"currentArticleView":currentArticle}];
        [currentScrollView addConstraints:self.lifeStyleContentSizeLayoutArray];
```

Above code snippet work perfectly fine on IOS 7.0 however, on IOS 6.0 an empty spaces is getting added (approx width is 760) to scrollview. if we examine visual format language it specify standard space (approx width is 20) need to be placed however, on iOS 6.1 it is around 760.

below is PO of an array which is storing all constraints.

```
<__NSArrayM 0xa4612f0>(
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xb331ff0; frame = (0 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb3335e0>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb334220 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb331ff0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb334450 H:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb331ff0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb3344b0 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb331ff0(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xa48ef80; frame = (338 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0xa48efe0>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb113d70 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa48ef80]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb11c6f0 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb331ff0]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa48ef80]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb11c730 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xa48ef80(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xb11f9a0; frame = (676 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0xb120d70>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb12f630 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11f9a0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb137f90 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xa48ef80]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11f9a0]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb1125b0 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11f9a0(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xa494550; frame = (1014 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0xa4940f0>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa4969e0 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa494550]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa496dc0 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11f9a0]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa494550]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa496e00 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xa494550(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xb468730; frame = (1352 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0xb465060>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb46a8d0 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb468730]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb46acd0 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xa494550]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb468730]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb46ad10 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb468730(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xb11c200; frame = (1690 0; 330 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0xb138850>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb129850 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11c200]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb11f400 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb468730]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11c200]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb11d620 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11c200(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<ArticleSummaryView: 0xb3197d0; frame = (0 0; 1004 768); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 6; layer = <CALayer: 0xb328b70>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb335240 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb3197d0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb335640 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb11c200]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xb3197d0]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb335680 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb3197d0(330)]>"
    );
},
{
    ArticleView = "<**ArticleSummaryView: 0xa496ce0;** frame = (0 0; 1004 768); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 7; layer = <CALayer: 0xa495d90>>";
    Const1 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb44ba00 V:|-(0)-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa496ce0]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>"
    );
    Const2 =     (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb449490 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xb3197d0]-(NSSpace(8))-[ArticleSummaryView:0xa496ce0]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb40e830 H:[ArticleSummaryView:0xa496ce0(330)]>"
    );
}
)
```

Content size layout po is given below

```
<__NSArrayM 0xb10df00>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb11fa00 H:**[ArticleSummaryView:0xa496ce0]**-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0xa462890 )>
)
```

Any help/solution/suggestion/work around will highly appreciated.

Thanks for your precious time.